# I need to fetch all field and access from permission set for perticular Object

Tags: soql, query, account, permission-sets

I am having one permission set and I want for Account object all field and their access like the below format:

```
Field Name     |        Read Access      |     Edit Access
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can generally query that as follows:

```
select field, permissionsread, permissionsedit from fieldpermissions where parentid = '0PSXXXXXXXXXXXX'
```

There doesn't appear to be a way to filter by a specific object, but it would be trivial to sort by the field name and find just those that start with "Account".

Comment: what is the parentid here

Comment: @dem The Id of the PermissionSet you want to query.

Comment: Thanks very much.We can use sObjectType to query perticular Objects Permissions as well.Thanks really appriciated

Comment: @dem You're most certainly welcome. I am glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do that using **Field Level Security**. Go to your permission set and search for **Object Settings** or in case of Profiles search for **Field Level Security** then select the respected object and give access to fields such as **Read/Edit**. Please refer below snapshot for giving **Field Level Security** using permission set. I've highlighted the section.
[image]

Comment: I dont want to provide permission .I just need  to fetch those permission in excel sheet.

Comment: @dem I think it is not possible. Similar idea has been already posted. You can [click here](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000iGzZAAU). I would suggest to use dataloader.